# Option array list linked to another option array list

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, node-commander

I'm building a command-line interface (CLI) in Node.js using the 'commander' library. I've created a command called 'groupBy' which accepts two options:

```
'--paths' for a list of file paths.
'--jsonPaths' for a list of JSON paths.
```

I can successfully print something like this:

```
$ index.js groupBy --paths path1 path2 --jsonPaths jsonPath1 jsonPath2
In the given files path1, path2
I want to show jsonPath1, jsonPath2 values
```

Now, I want to add the ability to filter by values for specific JSON paths and print something like this:

```
In the given files path1, path2
I want to show jsonPath1, jsonPath2, jsonPath3 values
Not filtering on jsonPath1
Filtering by value1 on jsonPath2
Filtering by value2, value3 on jsonPath3
```

I'm struggling with the correct command structure and 'commander' implementation. I had an idea to use a command like this:

```
$ index.js groupBy --paths path1 path2 --jsonPaths jsonPath1 jsonPath2 jsonPath3 --filter jsonPath1 '' --filter jsonPath2 value1 --filter jsonPath3 value2 value3
```

However, when using 'commander,' the 'filter' option generates an array like this: `[jsonPath, '', jsonPath2, value1, value2, value3]`. I can't distinguish between JSON paths and values, and I can't determine which values apply to which JSON paths.

I'm looking for a way to implement this functionality with 'commander.' Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

'commander' library let [customize option processing](https://github.com/tj/commander.js#custom-option-processing)
It let replace the default string array by anything else.
So it is possible to use an array of object like this :

```
[
     {
         jsonPath: "jsonPathX",
         jsonValues: [ "value1", "value2" ]
     }
]
```

where jsonPath is the first arg of the option, and jsonValues are the others args of the option :

```
-f jsonPathX value1 value2
```

Have to apply argParser(value, previous) method on the Option object after the creation and before the addition to the command.

```
const groupBy = new Command()
groupBy
    .addOption(
        new Option (
            '-f, --jsonFilters [jsonPath jsonValues...]', 
            'description'
        )
        .argParser((value, previous) => {
            // Implementation
        }
    )
```

`argParser` will be called for every arg of the option.
`value` is the current arg
`previous` is the value returned by the previous call, the first time his value is undefined.
The final value of `filters` depend of the last value returned in the last call to `argParser`

In each call, there is no no easy way to differenciate args from a first filter to the others.
Have to parse all the args ourself.
We can access to them by using `parent.args` property on the current command object `groupBy`.

In each call, it is not easy to know what arg is already parsed.
So I choice to calculate the final result at the first call and return it.
In the other calls, do nothing except returning the previous result.

```
        .argParser((value, previous) => {
            if (previous) // not the first call (!== undefined) 
                return previous // return result already generated

            // the first call, have to generate result
            const result = []

            // First keep only the filters options like -f, --jsonFilters and their args
            let filtersArgs = []
            let currentFilterOption = false
            for (const arg of groupBy.parent.args.slice(1)) {
                if (arg.slice(0,1) === '-' ) 
                    currentFilterOption = ['-f', '--jsonFilters'].includes(arg)
                if (currentFilterOption)
                    filtersArgs.push(arg)
            }

            // while there are args to proceed
            while (filtersArgs.length) {
                // Proceed the first option group
                const nextArgs = filtersArgs.slice(1)
                const indiceNextOption = nextArgs.findIndex(arg => ['-f', '--jsonFilters'].includes(arg))
                const currentArgs = indiceNextOption < 0
                    ? nextArgs
                    : nextArgs.slice(0, indiceNextOption)
                filtersArgs = currentArgs.length
                    ? filtersArgs.slice(currentArgs.length + 1)
                    : filtersArgs.slice(1)
                const indexAlreadyFiltered = result.findIndex(({jsonPath}) => jsonPath === currentArgs.at(0))
                if (indexAlreadyFiltered > 0) {
                    for (const arg of currentArgs.slice(1)) {
                        if (! result.at(indexAlreadyFiltered).jsonValues.includes(arg))
                            result.at(indexAlreadyFiltered).jsonValues.push(arg)
                    }
                }    
                else {
                    // Allow empty jsonValues if only one arg, have to raise an error in this case in the action method
                    result.push({
                        jsonPath: currentArgs.at(0),
                        jsonValues: currentArgs.slice(1)
                    })
                }
            }
            return result
        }
    .action(async (options, command) => {
        const {
            paths, jsonPaths, jsonFilters
        } = command.opts()
        const filtersMissingParams = jsonFilters.filter(({jsonValues}) => ! jsonValues.length)
        if (filtersMissingParams.length > 0) {
            Log.error("A filter must contain more than one param.")
            Log.error("This filter(s) are invalid(s) :")
            for (const {jsonPath, jsonValues} of filtersMissingParams) {
                Log.error(jsonPath, jsonValues.join(' '))
            }
            command.help()
        }
    })
```